# How can I increase the maximum number of websocket connections on my local machine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am writing a game using websocket with [ws module](https://github.com/websockets/ws) and I try to create some virtual websocket connections on my local computer to test it. However when I created more than 250 connections it gives an error:

```
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:9999
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1014:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1037:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1138:14)
```

How to remove this error and get more connections for testing? I don't get the error when the connection number is in the range of 1 - 210. But over 210 sometimes I get this error and if the connection number is over 250 I always get this error. I am not sure what causes this error. Is it because my computer is not capable of handling so many local connections? I am using OSX Yosemite (10.10.5)

Comment: Are you using Redis server to use web-socket ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay No I am not. I just use node.js.

Comment: Do you have a minimal, verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Just found out this:

[Increase TCP max connections on OSX](http://b.oldhu.com/2012/07/19/increase-tcp-max-connections-on-mac-os-x/)

The reason is that the max open files number is limited in OSX Yosemite. I just need to change the max open files number and the max connection number.

I will put the commands from the above link here:

increate max open files

```
$ sysctl -a | grep files
kern.maxfiles = 12288
kern.maxfilesperproc = 10240
```

kern.maxfiles and kern.maxfilesperproc were small numbers, they need to be increased:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=12288
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=10240
```

after this, you can increase your account’s limit by ulimit -n:

```
$ ulimit -n 10240
```

increate max sockets

```
$ sysctl -a | grep somax
kern.ipc.somaxconn: 2048
```

It was a small number and need to be increased:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.ipc.somaxconn=2048
```